# How do we know transconductance and diffusion resistance in this question?

Tags: transistors

I know the formulas of **gm** and **rπ**, however, VT is not given.

So, knowing these values R1= 51.2kΩ, R2=9.6kΩ, RC= 2kΩ, RE=0.4kΩ,
ICQ = 1.81mA,
VBE = 0.7V and β= 100

can we find gm and rπ because in the solution part of the book, it was written directly.

[image]

Comment: You can assume room temperature T=290K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\$V_T\$ is the thermal voltage, and is given by the formula:

$$V_T = \frac {kT} q$$

where \$k\$ is the Boltzmann constant (1.38e-23 J/K), \$T\$ is the temperature in Kelvin, and \$q\$ is the charge of an electron (1.6e-19 C). At room temperature, \$V_T\$ is about 25.9 mV

Answer (score 0):

1) The transconductance gm is the slope of the function Ic=f(Vbe).
Because this function has an exponential shape the slope (differential quotient) can easily be derived. And the result is **gm=Ic/VT** (Ic is the collector DC current).

2) Because the input resistance rπ is the inverse slope of the exponential curve Ib=f(Vbe) and because of Ic=beta*Ib we easily can derive that we have 
**rπ=beta/gm**.